# How to install Okular under SUSE (on a server)?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, pdf

I would like to install the pdf viewer Okular on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11. I am familiar with `apt` under Ubuntu, but on SUSE, I only found `rpm` to install `.rpm` files. I am wondering how Okular (or essentially any other program) can be installed? I know Okular is KDE, but I saw it [here](http://en.opensuse.org/Application_equivalents) so I hope it is possible to install it (I hope this is not a ridiculous question).

Comment: Can somebody explain to me why this question was downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SLES [zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aZypper_usage) is the equivalent to `apt` in Debian and `yum` on RHEL. You can install Okular with the following:

```
zypper in okular
```

Another option is to use the [YaST](http://en.opensuse.org/Portal%3aYaST) interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get "Root privileges are required for installing or uninstalling packages." Is it possible to install it 'locally' (to ~)?

Comment: @MariusHofert yes, but not using the system-wide package manager. I would recommend asking the administrator to install it.

Answer (score 1):

The SUSE equivalent is called zypper, and the commands are pretty similar : `zypper install`(short form `zypper in`) `okular` should do it. Check the `zypper` manual for other commands.